# Don't delete public puppet modules after rspec-puppet tests are done

Tags: rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

In `.fixtures.yml`, there are modules downloaded from a public library, such as stdlib and concat in the following example:

```
fixtures:
  forge_modules:
    stdlib: puppetlabs/stdlib
    concat: puppetlabs/concat
```

These modules need to be downloaded whenever running an rspec-puppet test. They also get deleted after tests are done.

It is good if all tests run completely. But if there is a failed test that needs to run separately, these modules are not available. I have to run all tests (100+) together, thus public modules can be downloaded and available. It is very annoying when I am debugging a small error.

Is there way to configure rspec-puppet so that it doesn't download/delete those public modules every time?

Comment: puppetlabs-spec-helper is doing the downloading and not rspec-puppet. You can file a feature request for this if you want, or use something else to download your module dependencies for your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until recently, the Puppetlabs_spec_helper actually behaved the way you wanted it to, i.e. the fixtures directory was not cleaned unless all the tests pass.

I notice this patch [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs_spec_helper/commit/3338d0315713f7e7ae2600372ac119f5f9ea0034) changed that behaviour. For what it's worth, I also don't agree with that change.

Anyway, if you want the old behaviour, you could:

1. Use an earlier version of Puppetlabs_spec_helper.
2. Define a custom spec task.
3. Or just run `bundle exec rake spec_prep spec_standalone`.
4. Or if you just want to run the tests in one file, run `bundle exec rake spec_prep; bundle exec rspec spec/somefile_spec.rb --fail-fast`. (The `--fail-fast` option is useful when debugging failing tests and it causes rspec to abort on the first failure.)

To define a custom spec task with the old behaviour, add this to your Rakefile:

```
desc "Run spec tests and clean the fixtures directory if successful"
task :custom_spec do
  Rake::Task[:spec_prep].invoke
  Rake::Task[:spec_standalone].invoke
  Rake::Task[:spec_clean].invoke
end
```

If, instead, you want it to never, ever clean the fixtures directory:

```
desc "Run tests but don't clean up spec dir"
task :custom_spec do
  Rake::Task[:spec_prep].invoke
  Rake::Task[:spec_standalone].invoke
end
```

In either case, you would then run the tests using:

```
$ bundle exec rake custom_spec
```

Comment: I had thought it was a set in puppetlabs_spec_helper from puppet side. It actually is from Ruby side.  Commenting out the spec_clean is exactly doing what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: Great. You should mark the question as resolved then.